# Docker for Mac, data loss during delegated bind-mounts synchronization

Tags: performance, docker, synchronization, docker-volume, data-loss

Docker for Mac [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#delegated) for bind-mounts performance tuning says the following regarding `delegated` bind mounts:

> If changes to the mount source directory are present on the host file system, those changes may be lost when the delegated mount synchronizes with the host source directory.

1) Does that mean that if I have a `delegated` bind-mount on my project source directory, then at some point my uncommitted changes can be lost during synchronization between container and host ? How often does that happen and are there any known preconditions for that to happen ?

2) Do I understand correctly that this issue happens only in case when changes from container itself are synchronized to the host(and not the other way, when changes from host are synchronized to container) during which the file changed on the host is overwritten with the same file changed on the container ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically it means if the host has changed a file and the guest has changed a file (which it does asynchronously in `delegated`), then the guest change may overwrite the host change. In `cached` the guest won't write asynchronous so that situation does not occur.

However, as far as I know, `delegated` mounts aren't implemented in docker for mac yet and behave the same as `cached`. Here is the issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1592

I wouldn't worry about source code changes disappearing. The synchronisation from guest to host is asynchronous but will happen nearly immediately. As long as you aren't trying to edit a file which you application writes continuously to, you would have to be very unlucky.

If you want to be sure or don't expect your application to write into that folder use `cached`. As mentioned above, there is no difference yet.